# Swapping of elements

Tags: list-manipulation

This is my

```
list = { xp[1]->-0.22245453730291873, xp[2]->0.0308657,xp[3]->0.49903825430681542,xp[4]->-0.491050690290500302,xp[5]->0.21102800632218013,xp[6]->0.0213929,xp[7]->0.28333403464313356,xp[8]->0.0335391,xp[9]->0.31494921279742938,xp[10]->-0.17576685427877437,
  xp[11]->0.0414688,xp[12]->0.31020940567773964,xp[13]->0.32216783070569416,xp[14]->-0.49024347906124188,xp[15]->0.0308204,xp[16]->-0.48930776427295686,xp[17]->0.38781414134352915,xp[18]->-0.42112529129272808,xp[19]->0.032357,xp[20]->-0.229036030243827710,
  xn[1]->-0.24212975266001929,xn[2]->-0.25516397005091557,xn[3]->0.33479444189166097,xn[4]->0.232911190737884438,xn[5]->-0.239542098908387319,xn[6]->0.0169672,xn[7]->0.332092041438385277,xn[8]->-0.245575774654965717,xn[9]->-0.422672696917404833,xn[10]->0.256374664851535206,
  xn[11]->0.39800704049391966,xn[12]->0.253444639060130428,xn[13]->-0.21711686587383844,xn[14]->-0.25412612413695251,xn[15]->-0.248636677542745793,xn[16]->0.25591982468868285,xn[17]->0.22876179760882395,xn[18]->0.29171372603830115,xn[19]->-0.24670297008965947,xn[20]->-0.22931967183419066
}
```

I have to swap the elements within this list. for example:

```
swap[list, xp[[1]], xp[[21]]];
```

meaning I have to interchange the elements of `Xp` and `Xn`, upto all 20 elements of `Xp` and `Xn`. Also I have this same list 15000 different values. So how can I change the value for single list and then use a `Do[]` loop to do this for all other 15000 different files.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you just trying to interchange a pair of elements, or something else?

Comment: The basic request is to do some kind of swap.  The example does not make it clear what the expected output is from a swap: does only one pair swap?  Is a pair always from the same head (i.e., both `xp` or `xn`), or will you also swap across heads?

Comment: @IgorRivin- What I am looking for is that I can replace the xp[[1]] with the xn[[1]] element and this series goes upto 20 elements. So when I generate the list after swaping I should get the the first element to be xn[[1]] and the 21 element to xp[[1]] and respectively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I understand the question correctly,

```
Permute[xp, Cycles[{{1, 21}}]
```

will do the needful. Notice that this works to effect an *arbitrary* permutation of the elements.

Comment: I have tried working with the below codes:

ListA = Table[sdata[[i, 3, 2]], {i, 1, 14982}];
then when created a list then
I used 

SetAttributes[swapA, HoldFirst];
swapA[ListA1_, aA_, bA_] :=
 With[{temp = ListA1[[aA]]},
  ListA1[[aA]] = ListA1[[bA]];
  ListA1[[bA]] = temp]
swapA[ListA, 1, 21]

to work on the list. but my value within the list are not interchanging. It is interchangeing the whole list with the other list at position 21. I am getting xp[[1]] at position 1 and xp[[1]] at position 21.

Comment: @TusharGoyal I have NO idea what you are talking about.

Comment: The simple question is how can I swap the elements within this list provided? I would like to replace first 20 elements within the list with the last 20 elements in the same order

Comment: @TushanGoyal Hint: to interchange the first two with the last two, do

Comment: `Permute[xp, Cycles[{{1, 20}, {2, 21}}] `

Comment: I can do this. But I have do write this like 20 times for single list and then I have to do this for another 14982 times.. Because I have that much list. Any shortcuts you know

Answer (score 2):

In:

```
list = {xp[1] -> -0.22245453730291873, xp[2] -> 0.0308657, 
   xp[3] -> 0.49903825430681542, xp[4] -> -0.491050690290500302, 
   xp[5] -> 0.21102800632218013, xp[6] -> 0.0213929, 
   xp[7] -> 0.28333403464313356, xp[8] -> 0.0335391, 
   xp[9] -> 0.31494921279742938, xp[10] -> -0.17576685427877437, 
   xp[11] -> 0.0414688, xp[12] -> 0.31020940567773964, 
   xp[13] -> 0.32216783070569416, xp[14] -> -0.49024347906124188, 
   xp[15] -> 0.0308204, xp[16] -> -0.48930776427295686, 
   xp[17] -> 0.38781414134352915, xp[18] -> -0.42112529129272808, 
   xp[19] -> 0.032357, xp[20] -> -0.229036030243827710, 
   xn[1] -> -0.24212975266001929, xn[2] -> -0.25516397005091557, 
   xn[3] -> 0.33479444189166097, xn[4] -> 0.232911190737884438, 
   xn[5] -> -0.239542098908387319, xn[6] -> 0.0169672, 
   xn[7] -> 0.332092041438385277, xn[8] -> -0.245575774654965717, 
   xn[9] -> -0.422672696917404833, xn[10] -> 0.256374664851535206, 
   xn[11] -> 0.39800704049391966, xn[12] -> 0.253444639060130428, 
   xn[13] -> -0.21711686587383844, xn[14] -> -0.25412612413695251, 
   xn[15] -> -0.248636677542745793, xn[16] -> 0.25591982468868285, 
   xn[17] -> 0.22876179760882395, xn[18] -> 0.29171372603830115, 
   xn[19] -> -0.24670297008965947, xn[20] -> -0.22931967183419066};
list[[RotateLeft[Range[40], 20]]]
```

Out:

```
    {xn[1] -> -0.24213, xn[2] -> -0.255164, xn[3] -> 0.334794, 
 xn[4] -> 0.232911190737884438, xn[5] -> -0.239542098908387319, 
 xn[6] -> 0.0169672, xn[7] -> 0.332092041438385277, 
 xn[8] -> -0.245575774654965717, xn[9] -> -0.422672696917404833, 
 xn[10] -> 0.256374664851535206, xn[11] -> 0.398007, 
 xn[12] -> 0.253444639060130428, xn[13] -> -0.217117, 
 xn[14] -> -0.254126, xn[15] -> -0.248636677542745793, 
 xn[16] -> 0.25592, xn[17] -> 0.228762, xn[18] -> 0.291714, 
 xn[19] -> -0.246703, xn[20] -> -0.22932, xp[1] -> -0.222455, 
 xp[2] -> 0.0308657, xp[3] -> 0.499038, 
 xp[4] -> -0.491050690290500302, xp[5] -> 0.211028, 
 xp[6] -> 0.0213929, xp[7] -> 0.283334, xp[8] -> 0.0335391, 
 xp[9] -> 0.314949, xp[10] -> -0.175767, xp[11] -> 0.0414688, 
 xp[12] -> 0.310209, xp[13] -> 0.322168, xp[14] -> -0.490243, 
 xp[15] -> 0.0308204, xp[16] -> -0.489308, xp[17] -> 0.387814, 
 xp[18] -> -0.421125, xp[19] -> 0.032357, 
 xp[20] -> -0.229036030243827710}
```

Comment: Table[ListA[[i]][[RotateLeft[Range[40], 20]]], {i,14000}]