Using the m ;; n notation (Span) to generate lists of runs of integers
The following example is a minimal working example (MWE). My supervisor has two lists, startingList and desiredList, defined as follows:
startingList = Range[10]; (* ({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}) *)
desiredList = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8};

My supervisor wishes to rearrange startingList to obtain desiredList. There are numerous ways to do this, but I first suggested using Part and an ordering list {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8}:
(* METHOD 1: using Part and an ordering list {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,8} *)
(* (1a) *)
orderingList = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8}; (* brute force manual entry *)
desiredList == startingList[[orderingList]]
(* (1b) *)
orderingList = Join[Range[7], {9, 10, 8}]; (* using Range[7] joined with {9,10,8} *)
desiredList == startingList[[orderingList]]

(* OUTPUT: *)
(* True *)
(* True *)

Based on this concept of using Part, my supervisor asked me if it is possible to use "m ;; n"- or "m ;; n ;; s"-like notation to generate lists of runs of integers. I said I didn't think so, at least with functions built into Mathematica/Wolfram language. In other words, the following does NOT work to generate orderingList defined above and throws an error:
orderingList = {1 ;; 7, 9, 10, 8}
startingList[[orderingList]]

(* OUTPUT: *)
(* Part::pkspec1 *)
(* Part: The expression {1 ;; 7, 9, 10, 8} cannot be used as a part specification. *)

One can, however, use the "m ;; n" notation inside Part:
orderingList = Join[startingList[[1 ;; 7]], startingList[[{9, 10, 8}]]]
desiredList == startingList[[orderingList]]

(* OUTPUT: *)
(* True *)

But that's quite verbose.
So, my question is: do you agree that one cannot directly use 1 ;; 7 to replace, for example, Range[7], Range[1, 7], or startingList[[1 ;; 7]]?
Note
By the way, other methods to generate desiredList from startingList include the following:
(* METHOD 2: delete 8, then append 8 to the end *)
(* (2a) *)
desiredList == Append[Delete[startingList, 8], startingList[[8]]]
(* (2b) *)
desiredList == Insert[Delete[startingList, 8], 8, -1]
(* (2c) *)
desiredList == Insert[Delete[startingList, 8], 8, 10]
(* (2d) *)
desiredList == Join[Delete[startingList, 8], {startingList[[8]]}]

(* METHOD 3: swap the ninth and tenth elements, then swap the eighth and tenth elements *)
(* (suggested by this answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144785/ *)
(* to this question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/144782/ ) *)
orderingList = Permute[Permute[startingList, Cycles[{{8, 9}}]], Cycles[{{9, 10}}]];
desiredList == startingList[[orderingList]]

(* OUTPUT: *)
(* True *)
(* True *)
(* True *)
(* True *)

(* True *)


Is your question strictly about whether Span can achieve the ordering {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8}, or are you also looking for alternative solutions? I myself don't see anyway that Span can achieve that ordering, but I also don't see why restricting yourself to using Span would be advantageous.

In general you can't use Spans like that. You can convert them to explicit Ranges, though, which result lists with Apply(@@): Range @@ (1 ;; 1000 ;; 13). There are two exceptions, though: RandomSample and RandomChoice,  which for some reason accept spans as arguments (for instance RandomSample[1 ;; 1000 ;; 13, 1]). This has limitations, though; values have to be between 0 and 2^63-1 in modern systems.

startingList = Range[10]; desiredList = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 8}; orderingList = {1 ;; 7, 9, 10, 8}; desiredList === startingList[[Flatten[orderingList /. Span -> Range]]]

@BobHanlon Yeah, one can of course use /. Span -> Range too...

Here's how I understand the problem. There are two inputs, the starting list, call it in and the desired list, call it out. The problem is that given these two things, produce the desired list out: f[in_, out_] := out seems easiest. OK, so that can't be the real problem. Is the problem how to combine a sequence of Span arguments? This works if the indices are positive: partSeq[p__] := Flatten[{p} /. Span -> Range]; Range[10][[partSeq[1 ;; 7, 9 ;; 10, 8]]].  Don't know what to do about 3 ;; -2.

Oh, I see now I borrowed @BobHanlon's (and kirma's) idea. Oops. Well, the first part of my comment still holds. I don't quite see the point. Is it to have a convenient input format? I guess it's not that the actual use case involves large spans you wish to avoid expanding? Other ideas: Join[Take[data, {1,7}], Take[data, {9,10}], Take[data, {8}]]; foo = Range[10]; foo[[8 ;; 10]] = foo[[{9, 10, 8}]]; foo; Wedge = Range; Join[1\[Wedge]7, 9\[Wedge]10, {8}]; Flatten[=[1..7,9,10,8]].
